# How does healing prioritize for a Templar?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

So, I like to play the cleric/priest/healer in most games.  When I got into ESO, I picked up a templar kitty and started to play.  However, I noticed a glaring problem to my previous games and the way healing works: there is no targeting of allies.  In most MMO's, I have to target a fellow player and then hit my heal ability.  Now, with the one focused healing ability I have, it looks like it target's what's under my aiming crosshair.  Or, does it?  How does the healing target the player that it ends up healing?

Comment: I haven't played a healer, yet. For the opposite side, you can press TAB to focus one enemy in a skirmish. Maybe there is a similar function for healers.

Comment: I looked through all of the commands in the key bindings, and only one of them is under Targeting, which is the TAB to focus one enemy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you may be falling prey to your habits of healing on other MMOs. Don't feel to bad I do the same thing still, as I'm sure most do. Healing in ESO has purposefully moved away from the click targeting of the traditional MMO. ESO healing is supposed to be up close and personal for the most part, obviously if you can target well enough with your target healing spells you can from afar. Which brings me to targeting, there is a soft targeting box around everyone (typically referred to as the hit-box in most games) that if you aim at you will target and heal that person. Now if you miss their "hit-box" you will heal either the lowest health member in your party that is in range or yourself.

No more shall healers feel bored battling static health bars, now we must look at floating health bars and chase them.

Edit:

I have also found as I have started healing more that even when not aiming, yet within range of an ally with less health than you, your heal will heal them. I think this is a bit of a design flaw that is hopefully unintentional as it could make single target healing useless.

Comment: So...if I understand this right...  Person Under Crosshair > Lowest Party Member (including myself).  I guess that makes sense.  And if an ally runs in my way as I'm healing, then I accidentally healed someone else?

Comment: @CrystalBlue I don't mess around with single target healing a whole lot, but if you are aiming at your ally you will heal them unless they have full health, then you will heal yourself. Theoritically. I personally only use my single target heal for saving heals.

Comment: You may as well disregard all talk of targeted healing, it simply doesn't happen in real play, especially in the utter chaos that a dungeon PUG can become.  I rarely have a clue where a certain player is, let alone position myself well enough to ensure an accurate aim on them.  I find that heal is mostly about mashing the DOTs until you need a bigger pick-me-up.  But even then, a lot of what Desmadona says is true in practice...you have nowhere near the control you might wish for.

Answer (score 0):

ESO turns you into a pocket healer - making it effectively less fun than, say, Wildstar. Literally. If you want your heals to land on the people who deserve them, you must follow those people around and don't cast heals until those people are hurt. "Hi, my name is Des, I am at your beck and call."

Don't kid yourself into thinking people in groups will understand that you don't always have a choice about who you heal... They don't care and you still get blamed for their failures.

I have been a healer in damn-near every MMO and I don't find ESO healing any more fun than it was in Tera or Wow BC or Rift or even SWTOR. It just requires more movement than some games. In fact, having no choice but to heal idiots infuriates me. I like being able to dictate who Doesn't get a heal, but have no problem not being able to dictate who does. That guy who just pulled a whole room of mobs to you? Yep... he gets healed. That guy who AFK'd in a hallway - yep. he gets healed too.

Soft-targeting for all the heal spells I've tested will heal the closest/lowest health person period (I'm sure there's some complicated algorithm, but I'm too lazy to look it up). You can stand right next to a target and have him in your reticle and it will still heal the jerk over there. All my testing was done with me and my target out of combat, though, so maybe it's AI is smarter when in combat (doubtful). Heals don't seem to default to you or people in your party if there are hurt people outside your party. I wish it did, so I could stop healing morons who deserve to die.

When it comes down to it, if you want any control over who gets healed, you have to outsmart their AI by positioning and timing.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I agree with many of the points made here, even if they are delivered as nothing more that opinion.  I too, like to have a bit more control over delivering heals.  Especially now that I have a feel for where they'd be most effectively delivered.  And that is quite often _not_ the lowest health player at the moment.  I have often found myself mashing a heal just to ensure it hits the _next to lowest_ health player, because I am aware of a big hit that they are about to take.  Mitigation of damage is what's missing, I think.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Mitigation of damage is not missing (Steadfast Ward and Rune Focus).

Comment: @Desmadona You may have some points, but the way you are delivering the message is not exactly "right". "But I'm too lazy to look it up" -> then don't post, or post and just not say it. Apply the same principles you complain ppl don't respect in games to your answers (you complain about the lazy afk guy that leech xp, but you do the same thing in this answer).